# Loop through data sets, keep certain variables, save output somewhere else

Tags: database, loops, stata

I'm working on my first Stata project and I have around 30 huge datasets with hundreds of variables. I want a loop that goes through each of them, keeps only the variables I am interested in and saves the reduced form data sets somewhere else. Other solutions didn't work for me 1. because many other people want to overwrite their original sources: for me it is crucial that the original data set remains unmodified and I get the output saved somewhere else to work with. 2. I guess I made a syntax mistake, because I'm relatively new.

Here's what I've produced so far

```
cd Y:\MAIA\Data\Data2014\

foreach file{
keep nopnltNF NumMois ptwa Qu cvwp ctwpenwp
sort nopnltNF NumMois
save `file'.dta in Y:\MAIA\MyName\test_folder}
```

Resulting in the error
    invalid syntax
    r(198);

Comment: `foreach file` doesn't fit any of the allowed syntax patterns. There is always an `in` or an `of` as keyword. Beyond that, did you read in any data before doing this?

Comment: @NickCox No, I had my test file open, but now that you mention it, of course I need to do something so that the loop opens all my data sets one after another.
I think this should take care of it, however, it also gives me "invalid" as output...

foreach file in wd{

use ´file'

. keep nopnltNF NumMois ptwa Qu cvwp ctwpenwp

. sort nopnltNF NumMois

save `file'.dta in Y:\MAIA\MyName\test_folder}

Comment: The loop there does no harm but it's just a loop over one file starting with  `use wd` Note the `save` command is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach to getting a list of Stata files and looping over them.

```
// get a list of all Stata files in directory
loc datasets : dir . files "*.dta"

// location for transformed files
loc newplace "tmp"

// loop over each dataset
foreach f of local datasets {
    di as result "Reading `f'"
    use "`f'", clear
    keep nopnltNF NumMois ptwa Qu cvwp ctwpenwp
    sort nopnltNF NumMois
    save "`newplace'/`f'"
}
```

But, note that `append` can already handle multiple datasets, and has a `keep` option:

```
append using `datasets', keep(foo bar)
```

This will produce one dataset in memory.